# Connection validation error using postgresql jdbc 4.2 driver against a 9.3 database -- apparent case-sensitivity of SEARCH_PATH keyword

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, search-path

Using the jdbc4.2 implementation contained in postgresql-9.4.1212.jar, I generate an error when calling the java.Sql.Connection isValid() method on a connection to a postgresql 9.3 database (java8 and postgres both running on windows 7).

The path to producing the error is complicated but reproducible (will provide relevant code shortly) and involves a sequence of sql calls on a single db connection whose default schema is reconfigured prior to each use via an explicit execution of `SET SEARCH_PATH='[some schema]'`.

I find that the error occurs if and only if I render the `SEARCH_PATH` keyword using upper case (that is, the error does not occur if I execute `SET search_path='[some schema]'` - only when I execute `SET SEARCH_PATH='[some schema]'`).

Note that the *direct* effect of executing either variant is the same -- in both cases the default schema associated with the connection is changed to [some schema].  It's just that, eventually, a downstream call to `java.sql.connection.isValid()` causes the database to crash if I've used SEARCH_PATH instead of search_path.

I can see that the jdbc driver's implementation of java.sql.connection.setSchema() uses the lower-case variant; something that makes me think this apparent case-sensitivity may be a known issue, but I have found no mentions of it anywhere online.

Note that the problem does not occur if I either: (1) use an older jdbc driver (postgresql-9.3.1100.jdbc4.1.jar) with my 9.3 database, or (2) use the latest jdbc driver with a postgresql 9.6 database.

I'm wondering if anyone has run into this specific problem, and also, if there are other known incompatibilities b/w the 9.3 database and the latest jdbc driver.

Comment: I think you should report a bug to the PostgreSQL JDBC developers instead of asking a question here. Also note that _"I'm wondering if anyone has run into this specific problem"_ is usually not received well on Stack Overflow, and _"if there are other known incompatibilities b/w the 9.3 database and the latest jdbc driver"_ is pretty broad.

Answer (score 0):

The driver is failing to invalidate the prepared statement cache because it only detects `SET search_path=...` when the config parameter is lower case.

See line 2056 of [this commit](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/commit/17c8afb11c319255aeffc93617545181d20400a3).

I can't find an issue that describes this. Please have a look yourself and raise one if needed.

Comment: I will look around for a PG issue report and create one if necessary.  Thank you teppic.